# Где хранить и как обработать Response VK SDK Android?

Tags: android, java, vkontakte-api

Сабж. Вот пример кода. VKApiAudio, как я понял, хранит только одну аудиозапись, полученную из Response. Тогда как получить их в большом количестве? Есть класс, в котором их можно хранить, типа VKApiCommunityArray? И как работать с ними, например, выбрать только Название и Исполнителя?

```
public void onMyButtonClick(View view) {
    VKParameters params = new VKParameters();
    params.put(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, "1");
    params.put(VKApiConst.COUNT, "3");
    VKRequest requestaudio = new VKRequest("audio.get", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, "1", VKApiConst.COUNT, "3"));
    requestaudio.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);

            VKApiAudio audio = (VKApiAudio) response.parsedModel;

            if (audio == null) {
                Log.v("Ошибка", "Ничего не загрузилось");
            } else {
                Log.v("User name:", audio.artist + audio.title);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            super.onError(error);
            Log.v("l");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Я не эксперт, но судя по VKApiConst.COUNT, "3" в ответ должно прийти до трех аудиозаписей, а не одна.    
Хранить их, я думаю, можно в обычном списке (List)

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае это, скорее всего, массив VKList<VKApiAudio> из 3-х элементов.